# Multiplicities of total spin representations in a direct tensor product of an arbitrary number of (SU(2)) spin-1/2

Tags: group-theory, mathematical-physics

In the below, I phrase the question in a physics setting (given my background). The question concerns the direct (or tensor) product of an arbitrary number of SU(2) spin-1/2 objects. The objective is to find the general multiplicities of the resulting irreducible representations.

In general, the tensor product of two spins of sizes $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ may be written as a direct sum of all total spin representations from $S_{max}= S_{1}+S_{2}$ up to $S_{min} = |S_{1}- S_{2}|$. That is, the total spin may assume any of the $(2 \min{S_{1}, S_{2}} +1) $
values $$S_{tot} = S_{max}, S_{max}-1,S_{max}-2, ..., S_{min}$$

Thus, for instance, for the lowest non-trivial representations of SU(2), with $S_{1}=1/2$ and $S_{2} = 1/2$, we have the well known formula $$1/2 \otimes 1/2 = 1 \oplus 0$$

Here, $\otimes$ denotes the direct product and $\oplus$ the direct sum of the corresponding irreducible total spin representations (i.e., here $S_{tot} = 1,0)$. (Physically, $S_{tot}=1$ corresponds to the "triplet" states of two spin=1/2 objects such as electrons and $S_{tot}=0$ corresponds to the "singlet" state (there are $(2 S_{tot}+1)$ states that lie in any total spin $S_{tot}$ sector).

One may apply this relation iteratively to obtain the two trivial examples

$$1/2 \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2 = 3/2 \oplus 1/2 \oplus 1/2$$

$$1/2 \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2 = 2 \oplus 1 \oplus 1 \oplus 1 \oplus 0 \oplus 0$$

and so on.

Now here is the question. Is there a general closed form expression for the tensor product of an arbitrary number N of spin-1/2 objects? That is, what is

$$1/2 \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2 \otimes ... \otimes 1/2?$$

More precisely, what are the multiplicities of each of the allowed sector?

Alluding to the two examples above, for N=3 the multiplicity of the $S_{tot}=1/2$ sector was 2 while the multiplicity of the maximal spin $S_{tot} =3/2$ is unity (as it is for any N).

For N=4, the multiplicities of the $S_{tot}=1$ and 0 sectors were,
respectively, 3 and 2.

What is the multiplicity of a general total spin $S_{tot}$ sector when taking the direct product of a general number N of spin-1/2 objects?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I got that the multiplicity of spin $n/2-j$ as $\frac{n+1-2j}{n+1}\binom{n+1}j$ for $0\le j\le n/2$ just by considering the character of the representation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not as knowledgable about characters as I should be. (If time permits, I will be grateful if you may very briefly expand on how you obtained this.)